# htaccess redirect from other domain to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have more than 50 domains that all are pointed to one main domain.

Currently redirects are set up so that all of the pages for the other domains are redirecting to the same corresponding page on the main domain, giving us thousands of redirects, when really we just want one domain pointing to the other.

The redirects are functioning as follows.

XYZ Landing page -> ABC landing page

Example:

test.com/page -> 301 redirects to abc.com/page

We need all redirects should be changed to function as follows.

XYZ Landing page -> XYZ Primary Domain -> Main domain

Example:

test.com/page -> 301 redirects to test.com -> 301 redirects to abc.com

Comment: Why do you want to go to the base address of the first domain first, why not go directly to `abc.com`? You will hardly be able to do this doing pure rewriting anyway, at least if you do not want to append additional parameters to the URL when you go to `test.com` - because at that point, where do you expect the info that `/page` was requested originally to come from now? You would have to explicitly store it into a cookie or the session first, so that you have it available when the client requests `test.com`

Comment: There is a issue in google crawling(Google search console) is considered if we directly go to test.com without first domain.

Comment: Well then it boils down to that you will have to preserve the info that originally `/page` was requested somewhere, because otherwise that will be lost as soon as you make the client request `/` ... due to the stateless nature of HTTP.

Comment: The reason we want to direct all internal landing pages to
the one domain (and then redirect that domain to abc.com) is so that
Google recognizes this as a 1:1 domain redirect. If these other domains had different content at one point
that carried some kind of weight, then a 1:1 landing page redirect would be
okay; however, because they all had duplicated abc.com content, there is
no reason to have thousands of landing page redirects in place for pages that
shouldn’t have existed in the first place.

Comment: The goal of the 301 redirect is to pass any page value on to
the next page. Since these internal pages had no value, there is no reason for
all of the redirects. Also, we don’t want to inflate the links back to
abc.com as Google will see that they are of no value and it will hurt
our credibility.

Comment: Yeah alright, but that doesn’t change anything about the underlying problem. You won’t be able to transport this info via the URL, if the redirect has to happen without any additional GET parameters(?) - and with a cookie or (cookie-based) session you won’t have much luck either when Google is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Atlast i have found the solution.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^|\.)example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)test.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [R=permanent,L]
```